# How get resource path in static library project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, resources, static-libraries

I am using third party SDK in my library project, SDK contain one json file.I need to get the path of json file in one  method of  library project's class. that method is calling from my application(After library project added to my application).
I am using 10.10 (OSX Yosemite),iOS8.1,xcode 6.1 environment. Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am added that json file into under Build phases => CopyFiles of library project,But I am getting path is nil value.

Comment: did u find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSBundle`'s `pathForResource:ofType:` method. You also need to make sure you instantiate your `NSBundle` object with the correct bundle however, otherwise you will get a `nil` return value. I.e. `[NSBundle mainBundle];` will allow you to navigate the main app bundle but frameworks are separate bundles.

I tend to use `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[Obj class]];` method and just pass in a class of an object in the framework you want to access. E.g. to access UIKit resources you could pass in: `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[UIView class]];`